# Powerpoint slide master - page numbers aren't aligned to the same line

Tags: numbers, powerpoint, office-2013, page-numbering

I hope someone can help me, I have never created a slide master before and created one as good as I could

But when I use the template(?) slides the numbers on some page are NOT in the same line or row as the one before

### Example:

---

page 5 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNR8r.png
page 6 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iARli.png

from page 1 to 5 is exactly what I want it to look like, but from 6 to 10 the numbers are moved more to the right side of the page

### What I have tried:

---

- I tried to copy-paste the text box (or page number textbox) from page
  5 to 6 = Same output
- I tried to create a new slidemaster and copy the slide master from
  the old one to the new one without the footer page number box = Same
  output
- I tried to add more space or margin on the right side of the number =
  Moves too much to the left

### Conclusion:

---

I hate powerpoint